# If two inductors with different inductances are connected in parallel to a dc circuit, will they have the same current in them at steady state?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, inductance

Can the current division rule be applied to the inductors in steady state ? Wouldn't they have the same current in them if they are ideal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current-voltage relation of an ideal inductor is $v=L\ di/dt$, or equivalently,
$$i(t) = i(0)+\frac{1}{L}\int\limits_0^tv(\tau)d\tau.$$
Now consider the two ideal inductors in parallel, with currents $i_1$ and $i_2$, and the same voltage $v$ across both. If the battery is connected at time $t=0$, prior to which neither inductor has current flowing through it (i.e. $i_1(0)=i_2(0)=0$), we have
$$L_1i_1(t)=\int\limits_0^tv(\tau)d\tau=L_2i_2(t),$$
or
$$i_1/i_2=L_2/L_1.$$
This is the current division rule for ideal inductors in parallel. It is valid at all times, including at steady state. It is the same as the division rule for parallel resistors, with resistance replaced by inductance.

Note however that real inductors are not ideal: they have series resistances. If you wait long enough, the currents through them will be determined by their series resistances, not their inductances. So it is important to realize that result for ideal inductors will not normally match what you would measure in a real circuit.

To go a bit further, assuming the inductors are similar in geometry but have different numbers of turns $N$, we can expect the series resistance of each inductor to be approximately proportional to $N\propto\sqrt L$, with the current shared accordingly at steady state.

Comment: You're assuming the initial current through each inductor is zero. However, current may circulate around the loop formed by the parallel inductors. Thus, for unknown initial current, the idealized problem is indeterminate.

Comment: well, isnt di/dt zero at steady state ? and if so how can we use the equation L(di/dt) ? @Puk

Comment: @wonderingwhy Yes, that's why the inductor voltages are zero at steady state. However, there is a period of time after you connect the battery during which there is non-zero inductor voltage, which determines the currents at steady state.